# "Host 'machine name' is not allowed to connect to this MySql server."

Tags: mysql, localhost

After creating a program that interacts with MySQL, I have migrated the program over to a different Login. However, now I can't connect to the MySQL server, and I'm getting the error message

`Host 'machine name' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.`

The program is identical, and still using the same connection string

`server=localhost;database=db_name;uid=root;pwd=pwd;`

I believe the issue is to do with `localhost`, but I don't understand why 'this machine' cannot access MySQL on 'this machine".

Can anyone help me understand exactly what `localhost` means, and why it is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
localhost is 127.0.0.1
this machine is 192.168.10.25(example)
```

Comment: so why are they different? aren't they both in the same location (i.e. this machine?)

Comment: could you also define which address is which (i.e. localhost is IPV4/IPV6, this machine is "...?")

Comment: Yes, they are different. _Sorry fo my english._ localhost is alias for internal ip 127.0.0.1, and 'this machine' is alias for external ip of this machine. Different "doors" with different "keys", "locks" and security politics.